# Audio amplifier hardware

Tags: hardware, audio

We design a wooden box with a high-quality speaker inside. Inside the box we have a Raspberry Pi 2, which generates music. We need about 15 Watts power for the speaker, max. We could amplify the output of the phones jack. A better solution might be the onboard connector P5. Is there dedicated Raspberry hardware that connects with P5 and delivers enough power for "loudspeakers"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One nice solution would be to use TDA7297 stereo amplifier IC (2x15 watt stereo), and build a custom PCB:

[image: TDA7297 PCB]

You can even buy an amplifier based on this IC from Amazon:

[http://www.amazon.com/TDA7297-Version-Audio-Amplifier-Dual-Channel/dp/B00FR7PDUS](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00FR7PDUS)

[image: TDA7297 Amplifier Circuit]

I've tested this circuit, and it works fine with RPi.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Hifiberry products](https://www.hifiberry.com/) while the "newer" products use the GPIO pins, the [Amp+](https://www.hifiberry.com/ampplus/) (DAC + amplifier) and the [DAC+ board](https://www.hifiberry.com/dacplus/) share the following pins (see here  [GPIO usage](https://www.hifiberry.com/guides/gpio-usage-of-the-hifiberry-products/)):

- GPIO 2 and 3 for configuration
- GPIO 28 through 31 for the sound interface

but the "older" [DAC](https://www.hifiberry.com/dac) (not DAC+) on the other hand does not use any of the GPIO pins but the onboard sound connector P5. However it only works with the older Raspberry Pi models A and B - which makes me wonder why you seek to use the P5 connector with a Pi 2.

---

<sup>Disclaimer: I am not using any HiFiBerry boards as of now, so this answer is based on the available documentation only.</sup>